# How to get grep to exit immediately when command is received from netcat?

Tags: grep, netcat

I want to open a port and listen for a command, and when that command comes in, immediately run a script.

The best I've come up with is (the echo is a substitute for my script):

```
nc -lk 9999 | grep -q runcommand && echo "running command"
```

, then I run this to test:

```
echo runcommand | nc localhost 9999
```

Unfortunately it only seems to echo the text on the second time I send "runcommand"??

How can I make grep exit immediately, so my script will run immediately?

Comment: that works for me with Debian's `nc.openbsd` (package `netcat-openbsd`) if I remove the `-k` option

Comment: @ilkkachu I wanted it to ignore the wrong command coming in, and stay listening. But I think without `-k`, the `nc` will exit if the wrong command comes in.

Comment: ah, right. Though for what I got when testing was that with `-k` it just stays alive even when the `grep` exits... Now I'm wondering if there's differences between the variants and versions of netcat. I have two on my Debian, `nc.openbsd` and `nc.traditional`, I'm not sure if there's a third one too. But `.traditional` doesn't seem to have `-k`, so yours can't be that.

Comment: I threw some ideas in an answer, not sure if it works for you. Also, now that I check, I get your behavior on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

One problem a construct like `something | grep -q` can have is that after `grep` exits, the left-hand command doesn't see the pipe close until it tries to write to it. But with my netcat (`nc.openbsd` from Debian), it doesn't seem to ever exit if `-k` is given, even if `grep` does. Hence the `&&` never triggers. I did get the behavior you described with the netcat on macOS, though.

One possibility is to wrap netcat in a loop, this seems to work for me:

```
while true; do
    if nc -l 9999 | grep -q runcommand; then
        echo got correct string, exiting...
        break
    else
        echo got a connection, but not the correct string...
    fi
done
```

And of course if there's still a problem that just sending one line doesn't trigger netcat to exit, you could always send a dummy line after it to poke it:

```
printf "runcommand\n.\n" | nc localhost 9999
```

Not sure if this helps, and there might still be differences between the various netcats.